# Firebase Realtime Database Allow Overwriting Of Data If Nothing Has Changed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to be able to write data to my Firebase Realtime Database and have it trigger my Cloud Functions and my Client listeners. In my app the user can try and write some data to the database. Using Cloud Functions I sensor some of those changes, and write the final output to a different location in the database.

In scenario A, the Clients assume their data is accepted perfectly. If the Client chooses to upload a new set of data, but all the changes from the old set are denied by the Cloud Functions, the data in the final location will not change when the adjusted set is written there. This results in no event listeners being triggered on the Client, so it does not know that its data has been fully processed. This will cause the Client and database to get out of sync because the Clients original assumption was wrong and it did not receive an updated set of data.

In scenario B, the Clients wait to receive the new data set. If things play out the same as in scenario A, Clients can be waiting indefinitely for the new data. If the display doesn't update automatically, and I'll explain why below, the user is left hitting the refresh button indefinitely, wondering if the server is lagging or if there is something wrong with the connection.

The Client uses a list of toggles to select which data is uploaded. If I were to change which toggles were present, and which were presently toggled, when the new data is received, it could much around users, undoing their work or rearranging the list. The reason the Client would either have to wait for the server or assume success is it polls the server once to populate the display and whilst the user is making their selections the data is guaranteed to get out of date at some point.

If I could get my listeners to trigger when writing identical data over itself, using scenario A I could inform the user that their data has gotten out of sync and that they should refresh it.

I am open to any suggestions, but I am properly stuck on this issue. I'm not sure how I should approach it.